# extended view, onMeasure(), how to set/get margin

Tags: android, margin

When you create a custom component in the method **onMeasure** can specify the size and even with the indentation (by using **this.getPaddingTop()**, etc.).
The question is whether the method for calculating **onMeasure** get values ​​"**margin** ..."? Given that the use of "this.getLayoutParams ()" method in onMeasure not welcome - please give the correct canonical solution to set/get the value of "**margin** ...".

Example:

```
    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        int wSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode( widthMeasureSpec );
        int wSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize( widthMeasureSpec );
        int hSpecMode = MeasureSpec.getMode( heightMeasureSpec );
        int hSpecSize = MeasureSpec.getSize( heightMeasureSpec );
        int lMargin = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams()).leftMargin;
        int rMargin = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams()).rightMargin;
        int tMargin = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams()).topMargin;
        int bMargin = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)this.getLayoutParams()).bottomMargin;
        int wSize = 256, hSize = 256;

        if (wSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            wSize = wSpecSize;
        } else {
            wSize += this.getPaddingLeft() + this.getPaddingRight() + lMargin + rMargin;

            if (wSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                wSize = Math.min(wSize, wSpecSize);
            }
        }

        if (hSpecMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY) {
            hSize = hSpecSize;
        } else {
            hSize += this.getPaddingTop() + this.getPaddingBottom() + tMargin + bMargin;

            if (hSpecMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
                hSize = Math.min(hSize, hSpecSize);
            }
        }
        this.setMeasuredDimension( wSize, hSize );
    }
```

In this example, the calculated mean all right, we have considered the margin and padding, but the method of obtaining margin is not too elegant.

In addition this approach area component becomes more on the same margin and in obtaining sizes through **getMeasuredWidth()** and **getMeasuredHeight()** - calculations are not correct.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles